# Lead Custom Field Mapping

Tags: leads, lead-conversion

I created one new lead custom field of phone data type. while i am trying to map to other object fields(consider any object, whether it could be account/contact/opportunity), it is not giving option to select [showing None Available]. For more understanding of my query, please see the pic which i uploaded.[image]

can any one please give me solution.

Thanking you
KS Kumar

Comment: This mapping is being done where?

Comment: Your existing Phone data type fields on Account and Contact already mapped with existing lead fields under the standard Lead mapping. Try creating a custom field on Account on phone type and see if it comes up.

Comment: Hi @sfdcFanBoy, sorry sfdcFanBoy i can't understand what your trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create Custom field of Phone Type on the Object(Account/Contact/Opportunity). Please see attached

[image]